# Unable to display sensor reading from Respberry pi pico to android serial terminal through RC-06

Tags: python, thonny, rp2040

Code:

```
from machine import Pin, UART
uart = UART(0,9600)
while True:
  if uart.any():
    uart.write('t')        
    command = uart.readline()
    print(command)   # uncomment this line to see the recieved data
```

Connected RC-06 to respberry pi pico to port 0 and 1. I couldn't receive "t" on android serial terminal app. But respberry pi pico is receiving data from android terminal app.

Answer (score 0):

typically you have to set the DTR line, see [FAQ](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android/wiki/FAQ#user-content-I_am_using_an_Arduino_Uno_Sparkfun_Pro_Micro_or_other_Arduino_but_codeSerialwritecode_does_not_send_data) of usb-serial-for-android library